# Errors in command-line while running Java programs

Tags: java, command-line, javac

I have a complete Java program, but the way that my professor is going to check to make sure that the program is working correctly is through CMD using the command
 `"java Caesar input.txt output.txt"`

But the issues I am running into are that when I compile using "`javac Caesar.java`" it will compile and create a `Caesar.class` file in the folder, but when I try run it as "`java caesar input.txt output.txt`" it says Error: `Could not find or load main class caesar`.

What am I doing wrong here?
I can provide additional information as needed.

```
package caaesar;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Connorbboggs
 * Version 12.03.2017
 */
public class Caaesar 
{

private static Scanner sc;
private static FileWriter fw;
private static BufferedWriter bw;
private Scanner inp;
private Scanner outp;
//DecodeChar class provided by you
public static char decodeChar(int n, char ch)
{
    int ord;
    if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')
    {
        ord = ch - 'A';
        ord += n;
        ord %= 26;
        return (char)(ord + 'A');
    }
    else if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
    {
        ord = ch - 'a';
        ord += n;
        ord %= 26;
        return (char)(ord + 'a');
    }
    else
    {
        return ch;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //File input for decode.txt with the encrypted text
    File inputFile = new File(args[0]);
    //Output for the decrypted text
    File outputFile = new File(args[1]);
    try 
    {
        //input from inputFile
        sc = new Scanner(inputFile);
        int shift = sc.nextInt();
        String decoded = "";
        //while lines are available text is fed to inputFile
        while( sc.hasNextLine())
        {
            //Lines being fed into string line
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            //for loop to feed into decoded using decodeChar
            for(int i=0; i<line.length(); i++)
            {
                decoded += decodeChar(shift, line.charAt(i));                    
            }
            decoded += '\n';
        }
        //Just to verify that the text is decrypted
        System.out.println(decoded);
        try
        {
            //create a fileWriter for outputFile
            fw = new FileWriter(outputFile);
            //write "decoded" to the file
            fw.write(decoded);
            //close the file
            fw.close();
        }
        //exception catching
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    //more exception 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: A capital C is different from a lower case c.  Did you try both?

Comment: All Java identifiers are case-sensitive. `Caesar` and `caesar` are not the same identifier.

Comment: Right, sorry that was a typo, and using both uppercase and lowercase provide the same error. Here's a screenshot of exactly what's going on: https://gyazo.com/a39a5793fced9fc67b22abb22317957c

Comment: OK, so did a file called `Caesar.class` get created when you ran `javac`?  And does your `Caesar` class inside `Caesar.java` contain any kind of package declaration?  How about a method that starts with `public static void main(String[] ` ?

Comment: Yes a Caesar.class was created: https://gyazo.com/7b9b29aa825d0573dc952501efb8c18e

And here is a snip of the code, displaying the main class:
https://gyazo.com/d2e20b32fe2c8d72b9addac5d36575e6

After reading that commend i did try "java main decode.txt decoded.txt" which, again, yielded the same error.

Comment: If this is what you mean, these are source packages in NetBeans: https://gyazo.com/513bbad9402fed458fefd2e6eafcd1e4

Comment: post your full code here

Comment: Is there a package declaration at the top of Caesar.java?

Comment: You're using NetBeans... Rum and compile there. Not the CMD

Comment: The full code was edited into the original post

Comment: So you've got `Caesar.java` in one folder, and `Caaesar.java` in another.  Looks like you've managed to confuse yourself about which one you're actually compiling.

Comment: Lol no sorry, they both contain the exact same code and are in virtually the same location, I made the other class to make sure it wasn't a fluke...

Answer (score 0):

First of all `javac Caesar.java` should say file not found...

Your **Caaesar** class is part of the **caaesar** package.

The fully qualified class name is `caaesar.Caaesar`, which is how you run this class

Answer (score 0):

If your professor intends to run

```
java Caesar input.txt output.txt
```

then you need all of the following.  Spelling is important, and so is whether each letter is upper or lower case.

- Your code file must be called `Caesar.java`,
- The class in your code file must be called `Caesar`,
- The class in your code file must contain a method that starts with `public static void main(String[]`.
- There must be *no* package declaration at the top of the file.

Please try to meet all these conditions, and be fastidious about the details.